# Android multi-fragment layout in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-implicit-intent

Although I got my code to work, I now have no idea what it's actually doing.
My app is an RSS reader, and the main content is in a `Fragment` containing a `ListView` with `NewsStory` objects.  When a list item is clicked, it opens an `Intent` with the website linked from the RSS.

Now the problem is, I don't understand the `Intent` here, it's not the way I've ever used `Intent`s before.

Also, I have to make it so that when I change the orientation, the original profile `Fragment` takes up the left half of the screen and the linked webpage takes up the right half of the screen. I've tinkered around with it, to no avail. I did a bit of research on orientation changes, but I feel like doing things with `Fragment`s always changes how everything works.  Anyway, here's the `Fragment` code. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class HeadlineFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText input;
    Button search;
    ListView headlines;
    NewsDataSource ds;


    public HeadlineFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_headline,container,false);

        input = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
        search = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        headlines = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        try {
            ds = new NewsDataSource();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        headlines.setAdapter(new NewsDataSourceAdapter(this.getActivity(), ds));

        headlines.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String url = NewsDataSource.stories[position].getLink();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
    /*
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, regarding that `Intent`, its an implicit `Intent`. When you set the `action` as `ACTION_VIEW` and add a URI / URL as an extra, the OS gets the message that you want to open an app that can navigate to that URI / URL.

Secondly, for showing a two-pane layout in landscape mode, you'll have to show that RSS content in a `Fragment` instead of an `Activity` as you are currently doing, and you'll have to display those `Fragment`s side-by-side in an `Activity` in landscape mode. See the [**Retrieving a List of Contacts**](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html) example for a really good explanation of how to display a multi-pane master detail layout in portrait mode.

References:

**1.** [`Intents and Intent Filters`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

**2.** [`Planning for Multiple Touchscreen Sizes`](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/multiple-sizes.html).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, but couldn't find. Thank you very much.